# jquery scrollTo is not working for me

Tags: jquery

I have a simple use for the jquery scrollTo plugin.
An html table that gets rows added to over a period of time.
The table window holds 13 rows but in one session the table might grow to 40 or 50 rows.  What I would like to have happen is that once the 14th and subsequent rows are add it would always scroll to the newest (last) row in the table.  The table does get a vertical scrollbar when the 14th row is inserted.

I must be missing something because it's not working.
Here's the code:

```
<script src="jquery.scrollTo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and at the end of the function that is called to insert the new row:

```
$(".LOGROW").scrollTo( 'max', 1000, {axis:'y'} );
```

Every tr in the table has the LOGROW class.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _“Every tr in the table has the LOGROW class”_ – then you should maybe select the _last_ of those rows, and not all of them …?

Comment: Tried .LOGROW:last - still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I use jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to scroll to an element when needed, so that you don't even need a plugin.  It looks something like this:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#element").offset().top}, 500);
```

However, I see that you may just want to scroll the table within it's div.  So, make sure your table is wrapped with a div, and give it the css style `overflow: auto;` or perhaps `overflow: scroll;`

Assuming that your div has an id of "myDiv", you can try:

```
$("#myDiv").animate({scrollTop: $(".LOGROW:last").offset().top}, 500);
```

Finally, if all else fails, try giving your table and/or div wrapper css styles of `display: block;` and/or `position: relative;`.  Or, you may have to +/- with that offset value a little to get it exactly where you want to scroll.

I hope this helps!

edit: I just tested it, and it works for me, as long as the div wrapper has a height set.

Comment: Jon_o - you rock!  Yes, I did happen to already have a div around the table and it worked.  Thanks!